# Why does on Linux system from "scratch" without init and standard C library there are no stdin, stdout and stderr (0, 1 and 2 file descriptors)?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

i compiled linux kernel for my STM32 board, and i made simple application in assembler (no standard library) that writes string to stdout (file descriptor 1). That application is placed in /bin/init in initfs made at kernel compile time. So my program is the first started program with PID=1 (like normally init does).

Code below should normally write string on the screen (in my case, rs232 console):

write(1, "blabla", 6);

But it does not work... i receive -9 err:

```
[    0.838707] Run /bin/init as init process
[    0.845110] ksys_write(1, (ptrval), 64) = -9
```

I always thought that three first file descriptors are standard and opened by OS. But now i am confused.

**Who is responsible for opening standard file descriptors (0, 1 and 2) ? Does the init or standard library is responsible for that ?**

Comment: `init` is responsible for opening devices which will be used as stdin/stdout/stderr. Some `init` implementations use `/etc/inittab` to determine which devices to use.

Comment: Standard file descriptors are only opened in a "hosted" implementation. An OS kernel is a standalone implementation, the standard file descriptors are not opened.

Comment: In a Unix-ish environment a normal process inherits descriptors 0, 1, 2 from its parent. Since `init` is special in having no parent, it inherits nothing. Since `init` *is* a part of the OS, it's the responsibility of `init` to open these descriptors, so that *its* children have them opened by the OS.

Answer (score 4):

Traditionally, the `init(8)` process will invoke a copy of `getty(8)` for each terminal device that is to be used for logins, as defined in `/etc/inittab`.  On a modern system it may be done instead by `systemd`.

Then `getty` is responsible for opening fd 0,1,2 on its assigned  terminal device.  `getty` would then invoke `login(8)` which requests and verifies the user's login credentials and then starts their shell.   Open file descriptors are inherited across `fork` and `exec`, so no other process needs to open these file descriptors, except for purposes such as a shell setting up redirection or pipelines.

Linux distributions commonly use [`agetty(8)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/agetty.8.html).  You can see [here](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/640e93f48040e72b06f038159c54ffa3bbc86e0c/term-utils/agetty.c#L1119) where it opens the terminal device as fd 0, and [here](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/640e93f48040e72b06f038159c54ffa3bbc86e0c/term-utils/agetty.c#L1153) where it uses `dup(2)` to duplicate it to fd 1 and 2.

For logins by other means, setting up the fds would be handled by your X terminal program, `sshd`, or whatever else is going to start up your shell.

So saying that "they are opened by the OS" is only correct in the broad sense of "OS" which includes the basic system programs and daemons, and in that an ordinary user program doesn't have to worry about it.  The kernel has nothing to do with it - deciding how to open files is strictly a userspace function.  Nor does the standard library, since for a normal user program, the fds are already open when the program executes its first instruction, having been inherited from its parent.

So if you are writing your own system from scratch, you need to open an appropriate terminal device on those file descriptors, before running any other program that expects to see them.  You could decide whether to do this within your `init`, or delegate it to some equivalent of `getty`, or whatever makes sense for your design.

For initial testing purposes, you could simply open  `/dev/console`; see [Linux: Difference between /dev/console , /dev/tty and /dev/tty0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60641/linux-difference-between-dev-console-dev-tty-and-dev-tty0)